# does aws eks fargate pricing charge for the cluster only if you don't have any pods running

Tags: amazon-eks

if I create an EKS Fargate cluster and just keep it without deploying anything else on top of it do I still incur a charge.  From what I have seen it does not seem to incur a charge and when I went though the pricing here https://aws.amazon.com/eks/pricing/ [image]

I think you get charged only once you start to run your pods.  I want to confirm this.  I am not sure if AWS will charge for the control pane as mentioned here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I think you get charged only once you start to run your pods.

AWS managed control plane is a recurring charges, doesn't matter if you have worker node (eg. EC2, Fargate) or not. Also, supporting resources such as NAT, EIP are chargeable.